# MarkerWithLabel - drag event works like click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I set a marker on click on the map. I use MarkerWithLabel.

I use draggable marker.

If I drag a marker it works fine. But if I drag a label it works with click event on the map.

How can I use labels and can drag a label without click event?

In my example - when I drag a marker JS creates new marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {         
     addMarker(event.latLng)
});

function addMarker(latLng) {
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          labelContent: "example",
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
          labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
          labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
       alert(2);
    })
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4139/)

Comment: From documentation - click - This event is fired when the user clicks on the map (but not when they click on a marker or infowindow). But nothing about labels.

Answer (score 5):

You may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4182/)) unless you have other solution:

```
var map, dragended;
// ...

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    if(!dragended) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    }
    dragended = false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(target && target.className == 'labels') {
        dragended = true;
    }
    alert(2);
});
```

The `click` event is fired when you start dragging ([Check this](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/examples.html)). It's a dirty hack using a global variable but it works if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Their [example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/examples/events.html) page shows what you're looking for in action.

```
function your_function(e) {  //Callback function
    console.log("Drag: " + e.latLng.toString());
}

//Create map using the #map_canvas element
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

//Create new MarkerWithLabel (enhanced version of a Marker)
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716),
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,  //Attach to map
    labelContent: "example",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
    labelClass: "labels" // the CSS class for the label
});

//Finally add a listener to the marker to call your_function when "drag" event has occurred.
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", your_function );
```

That's all the magic you need, I guess.

---

**Edit:** Upon further investigation of your Fiddle, I noted a the event bubble leak from the marker label to map. Since there's no known way to stop the event propagation from bubbling into a different type, you can set a variable to keep track of this scenario and clear it once it's triggered. [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373677/google-maps-double-click-event-propagation). You can optionally just set an actual local variable in the same scope as map, either way will work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4183/).

Comment: If you drag a label the map creates new marker. But the map shouldn't react to drag a label.

Comment: Because of `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {         
     addMarker(event.latLng)
 });`

Comment: exactly. But I don't want it. I want to drag a markers and create it. Not a same time. From documentation -  click - This event is fired when the user clicks on the map (but not when they click on a marker or infowindow). But it doesn't work for label.

Comment: Let me see if I can clean up this Fiddle a bit.

Comment: The problem was somewhere in the packer code you provided for MarkerWithLabel. I replaced it with another version that was compressed with [JSCompress](http://jscompress.com) and everything just worked. Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4181/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not having issues with the updated code. On Chrome36 / Win7 x64. Checked in Firefox29 and IE10 too, all good. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/4183/) again. The issue was because of an odd event bubbling issue where letting go of the mouse button from dragging the label would trigger a click. I set a variable to help clear that as traditional methods to cancel won't work, [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373677/google-maps-double-click-event-propagation). You can optionally just set an actual local variable in the same scope as map, either way will work. Updated my answer.

Comment: I just noticed [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328828/markerwithlabel-drag-event-works-like-click-event/23378311#23378311). Ah well. Hope either way helped!

Answer (score 0):

try using [markerwithlabel.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js?r=131) change, its a code for the change in markerwithlabel.js. Through this you can avoid or ignore the click on label with marker dragend or label dragend.